# Route traffic between two webservers on demand

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, web-server

I have two Windows webservers in VM environment, Beside using my firewall (no access) is there an easy and reliable way for me to re-route my incoming traffic to a specific server on demand?

Lets say all the public traffic goes to server-a, if I want my traffic to change to server-b. How can I do that? Right now, I have a little script that swaps the IPs so server-a will have server-b IP and server-b will have server-a IP. Is there a better way?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you looking for a load balancing or failover solution or are you looking to just change the direction of ALL traffic at a given time?

Comment: Can we step back and take a look at what problem you are trying to solve by switching servers?

Comment: Sure, the problem is. I have two webserver, one is the live server, and one is just a minified testing server with a banner that tells my users that the site is under maintenance. All the traffic goes to the live server. I want it so that, I can forward all my traffic to the testing server so I can do some work on the live server. Once done, revert the traffic back to the live server. I can not do it through the firewall because it is a hosted cloud firewall and it is not an option for me! Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use load balancing for this. Windows has NLB built in, but it lacks some features of hardware load balances.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Load Balancing is to rewrite all incoming requests to point to a maintenance page.

In IIS7+ you can do this easily by adding a file called `app_offline.htm` to the root of your website.  IIS will check for this file and, if it exists, will issue a HTTP/503 with the content of the app_offline.htm file.

Since you have tagged this Apache2, perhaps you can do this with a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} != 503
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_offline.htm [R=503,L]
```

(Note, I'm not an Apache guy -- this was crudely adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5447534/415523)

Just remember that, any images/scripts/CSS would need to be inline (or data URLs), or served externally (e.g. via a static.yourapp.example.org site or CDN), as they might also be subject to the rewrite.